# How can I read byte array coming from server in UWP app?

Tags: tcp, uwp, client-server, hololens

I have a client-server app. The client is HoloLens 2 and the server is unity running on PC. I have created a socket using HoloLens but I can't read the byte array on HoloLens. In the connect method _inputStream and _outputStream are System.IO.Streams.

PC client uses `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient`, `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream` but UWP (HoloLens) uses `Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket`.

In the ReceiveCallback I have an issue with `int byteLenght = _inputStream.EndRead(result);` When I tried this code on HoloLens I got the exception: "System.ArgumentException: The specified AsyncResult does not correspond to any outstanding IO operation". But I tested it with PC client (System.Net.Socket) and everything works fine.

Btw, I gave all related permissions.

How can I read byte array in UWP app?

***Update:***

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        private void ConnectUWP(string host, string port)
#else
        private async void ConnectUWP(string host, string port)
#endif
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            errorStatus = "UWP TCP client used in Unity!";
#else
        try
        {
            socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
            Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName(host);
            _receivedData = new Packet();
            _receiveBuffer = new byte[DataBufferSize];
            await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, port);
            successStatus = "Connected!";

             _outputStream = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
             //_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_outputStream) { AutoFlush = true };
             
             _inputStream = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
             Task.Run(() => StreamToBytes(socket.InputStream));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorStatus = e.ToString();
            Debugger.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().text += "\n Exception: " + errorStatus;
        }
#endif

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        public async Task StreamToBytes(Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream stream)
        {
             using (var reader1 = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream))
             {
                reader1.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead;
                reader1.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                reader1.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

                //InBuffer is always 256, 
                //even if there is more data waiting. If I put a task.delay in it will always return 25
                try
                {
                    await reader1.LoadAsync(256);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //..
                }

                while (reader1.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                {
                    var bytes1 = new byte[reader1.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                    reader1.ReadBytes(bytes1);
                    _receivedData.Reset(await HandleData(bytes1));
                    await reader1.LoadAsync(256); 
                }
                reader1.DetachStream();
              }
        }

            private async Task<bool> HandleData(byte[] data)
            {
                int packetLength = 0;

                _receivedData.SetBytes(data);

                if (_receivedData.UnreadLength() >= 4)
                {
                    // If client's received data contains a packet
                    packetLength = _receivedData.ReadInt();

                    if (packetLength <= 0)
                    {
                        // If packet contains no data
                        return true; // Reset receivedData instance to allow it to be reused
                    }
                }

                while (packetLength > 0 && packetLength <= _receivedData.UnreadLength())
                {
                    // While packet contains data AND packet data length doesn't exceed the length of the packet we're reading
                    byte[] packetBytes = _receivedData.ReadBytes(packetLength);
                    
                    ThreadManager.ExecuteOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        using (Packet packet = new Packet(packetBytes))
                        {
                            int packetId = packet.ReadInt();
                            _packetHandlers[packetId](packet); // Call appropriate method to handle the packet
                        }
                    });

                    packetLength = 0; // Reset packet length
                    if (_receivedData.UnreadLength() >= 4)
                    {
                        // If client's received data contains another packet
                        packetLength = _receivedData.ReadInt();
                        if (packetLength <= 0)
                        {
                            // If packet contains no data
                            return true; // Reset receivedData instance to allow it to be reused
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (packetLength <= 1)
                {
                    return true; // Reset receivedData instance to allow it to be reused
                }

                return false;
            }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything for TCP but TCP is nearly impossible for HoloLens with UWP app. So I tried UDP and it works perfectly (https://github.com/mbaytas/HoloLensUDP). I hope Microsoft put a TCP example for HoloLens 1 and 2 in near future. Thanks Nico for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> When I tried this code on HoloLens I got the exception: "System.ArgumentException: The specified AsyncResult does not correspond to any outstanding IO operation".

Please refer to [`BeginRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.beginread?view=net-6.0#remarks) method document, *In the .NET Framework 4 and earlier versions, you have to use methods such as BeginRead and EndRead to implement asynchronous I/O operations. These methods are still available in the .NET Framework 4.5 to support legacy code; however, the new async methods, such as ReadAsync, WriteAsync, CopyToAsync, and FlushAsync, help you implement asynchronous I/O operations more easily.* I suppose this old api could not compatible with HoloLens device, so please try to use `ReadAsync` to replace like the following

```
 byte[] bytes = await StreamToBytes(_inputStream);
 public async Task<byte[]> StreamToBytes(Stream stream)
 {
     byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
     await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     return bytes;
 }
```

Or follow the official's processing that use `DataReader` to read ReadBytes, for more code please refer [streamsocket](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/StreamSocket).

**Update**

```
using (var reader1 = new DataReader(_inputStream)
{
    reader1.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    reader1.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
    reader1.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

    await reader1.LoadAsync(256); //InBuffer is always 256, 
                                  //even if there is more data waiting. If I put a task.delay in it will always return 25
    while (reader1.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
    {
        var bytes1 = new byte[reader1.UnconsumedBufferLength];
        reader1.ReadBytes(bytes1);
        await reader1.LoadAsync(256); 
    }
    reader1.DetachStream();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I tried it but I got another exception: "System.NotSupportedException: This stream does not support the Lenght property because it is not seekable". I used like "public async Task<byte[]> StreamToBytes(System.IO.Stream stream)" Is the stream you suggest is system.io.stream?

Comment: Ok, I got it, I have updated  the case reply that use DataReader to read bytes.

Comment: Hi Nico, I tried your answer and there is no exception this time however it doesn't work. After `reader1.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;` I got nothing: no exception, no byte array. I lost my debug in `await reader1.LoadAsync(256); `. I use `System.Net.Sockets` and `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream` on the server-side and stream the data as a byte array. Can we say if I want to send byte array from server to client, based on client device I need to change the stream? However, my server should work on the PC and I can't run UWP code on the server. Related to this?

Comment: It's not key point that use `System.Net.Sockets` in server and use `Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket` in HoloLens client. byte array is universal data between server and client.  Have you added async key-word in the method?

Comment: I have updated my question. I am glad to hear this otherwise it wouldn't make sense to me. Yes, I used async in my method.

Comment: I check your code, I found you miss  `await` key word in this line `try  {  reader1.LoadAsync(256);  }`

Comment: Yes you're right but the result didn't change - I got nothing. I tested with unity the code. The funny part even though I changed my platform to UWP, unity still uses `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient`. I did some research and people said "you can't run Windows lib in unity editor". I guess the only way to test the code is to deploy it to the HoloLens.

Comment: I guess I found the problem. The problem is  `await reader1.LoadAsync(256); //InBuffer is always 256` should be fixed size - not 256!. We gave 256 but the actual data in my case is 47. If I gave 47 like `await reader1.LoadAsync(47)` it works. How can I get the stream length?

Comment: 256 is buffer size but not stream length, it does not matter set buffer length as  256 or 47. and  your inputsream can't be seek, we can't get total length. if small buffer length could work, please try to set buffer as 16.

Comment: But I don't want a fixed buffer this way. Each incoming stream should carry a different size of data and I should be able to read every n-size stream.

Comment: I found the reason why `reader1.LoadAsync(256)` is not being called, if you set `InputStreamOptions` to `ReadAhead`, when the 256 buffer fills up, it will do the next step. please try to InputStreamOptions as `Partial`