# How can I get Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream inputStream length?

Tags: tcp, uwp, client-server, hololens, stream-socket-client

I use HoloLens 2 as a client and my unity server on my PC. (More discussion about this: [How can I read byte array coming from server in UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71496337/2922770)) I lost my debug `await reader1.LoadAsync(256);`. I tried everything to get my stream data but I couldn't. I don't want to const value for the buffer I need the exact stream size for the buffer. I tested this and it works only and only if the buffer size and data stream size is equal. Or you can suggest me other approaches?

```
// Create the StreamSocket and establish a connection to the server.
        using (var streamSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket())
        {
            // The server hostname that we will be establishing a connection to.
            var hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName(host);

            // client is trying to connect...

            await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port);

            // client connected! 

            // Read data from the server.
            using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream inputStream = streamSocket.InputStream)
            {
                using (var reader1 = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
                {
                    reader1.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead;
                    reader1.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                    reader1.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
                    
              
                    // Should be in stream size !!!
                    await reader1.LoadAsync(256);
                    
                    while (reader1.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                    {
                        var bytes1 = new byte[reader1.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                        reader1.ReadBytes(bytes1);

                        // Handle byte array internally!
                        HandleData(bytes1);

                        await reader1.LoadAsync(256);
                    }
                    reader1.DetachStream();
                }
            }
        }
        // close socket
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Nico sorry for the late update. I tried everything but TCP is nearly impossible for HoloLens with UWP app. So I tried UDP and it works perfectly (https://github.com/mbaytas/HoloLensUDP). I hope Microsoft put a TCP example for HoloLens 1 and 2 in near future.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream inputStream length?

`IInputStream` of `SteamSocket` can't be seek. So we can't get length of steam, That's why we need set a buffer to load input stream all the time until the stream finished.

I checked code above, if you have set `InputStreamOptions` as `ReadAhead`. It will do the next step, when the 256 buffer fills up, please try to InputStreamOptions as `Partial`.

```
reader1.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead;
```

**Update**

If you want to get length of current message before load it, we suggest you write the message length as message header into to the steam.

For example

```
string stringToSend = "PC client uses System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient, System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream but UWP (HoloLens) uses Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket.";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSend);
writer.WriteInt32(bytes.Length);
writer.WriteBytes(bytes);
```

**Receive client**

```
while (true)
{

    // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
    uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
    if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
    {
        // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
        return;
    }

    // Read the string.
    int bytesLength = reader.ReadInt32();
    uint Actualbytelength = await reader.LoadAsync((uint)bytesLength);
    if (Actualbytelength != bytesLength)
    {
        // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
        return;
    }

    // Display the string on the screen. The event is invoked on a non-UI thread, so we need to marshal
    // the text back to the UI thread.

    var bytes = new byte[Actualbytelength];
    reader.ReadBytes(bytes);

}
```